# Grouping svelte components

Tags: javascript, svelte

I was curious if there is any way to sort of group svelte components together.

What I am doing now is this

```
import Button from "./common/Button.svelte";
import Link from "./common/Link.svelte";
import Text from "./common/Text.svelte";
```

But it would be nice to group them so that I could write something like this

```
import {Button, Link, Text} from "./common";
```

Is this possible?

I've tried just creating a js file

```
import Button from "./Button.svelte";
import Link from "./Link.svelte";
import Text from "./Text.svelte";

export default {
  Button,
  Link,
  Text,
};
```

But when I try to use it I just get the error `Text is not a constructor` so I assume that I am doing something wrong there

Comment: Would a [barrel file](https://medium.com/@klauskpm/do-a-barrel-export-aa5b79b76b05) work?

Comment: unfortunately no. I get the same error

Answer (score 4):

This seems to have been the solution

```
export { default as Button } from "./Button.svelte";
export { default as Text } from "./Text.svelte";
export { default as Link } from "./Link.svelte";
```